# Trigger angular 4 function when finger is off the screen and content is still moving on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, events, ionic3

I am trying to fix header while the user is scrolling, at some point of the page. The problem is that on iOS javascript function is not triggering all the time, but only while finger is on the screen. I can catch touchstart, touchend, touchmove events but none of this work, because content is still moving when finger is off and at some point header should be fixed and its not cause javascript doesnt detect that something has changed.

Any ideas?

I am using absolute position for fixing insted of fixed because of the known ios problem with fixed position.

**NOTE: I am using cordova 7.0.1 and ionic 3.19.1, angular 4.**

```
<ion-content>
<header>Example</header>
<p>something somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomethingsomething somethin gsomet hingsomething</p>
</ion-content>


ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, false); 
    }
scroll = (): void => {
    if(this.header.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top < -10 ) {
      this.isFixed = true;
    } else {
      this.isFixed = false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Include your code

Comment: Thanks, i just added a piece of it, so you get get an idea of what im trying to do, but i would prefer just an explanation of how to do this rather than getting a code